# Plotting Agglomerative Hierarchical Clustering with complete linkage

Tags: r, hierarchical-clustering

I need to do a visual rappresentation of Hierarchical clustering using Complete Linkage by plotting an dendogram.

My data.frame is obtained from eurostat database (CP00 - HICP) and after some cleaning looks like:

> dput(head(CP00))

```
structure(list(id = c("CP00", "CP00", "CP00", "CP00", "CP00", 
"CP00"), country = c("Austria", "Austria", "Austria", "Austria", 
"Austria", "Austria"), time = structure(c(10988, 11017, 11048, 
11078, 11109, 11139), class = "Date"), values = c(1.9, 1.9, 1.8, 
1.6, 2.4, 1.9)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

With 7344 observation.

Firstly, I computed the Dissimilarity matrix with and then the hierarchical clustering using complete linkage:

```
# Dissimilarity matrix
CP00_clst <- dist(CP00, method = "minkowski", p = 1.5)

# Hierarchical clustering using Complete Linkage
CP00_clst <- hclust(CP00_clst, method = "complete")
```

Finally, simply plotting with a title:

```
# Plot the obtained dendrogram
plot(CP00_clst, main = "Clusterin Countries based on HICP")
```

However, the result is what I need to have, such as a clear dendrogram. In addition, I need to divide the dendogram in 4 cluster.

This is my results:

[My Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6Jph.png)

This is the outcome that I need:

[Outcome needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oK5n1.png)

I am new to R and probably there is something wrong in the dissimilarity matrix. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you provide `dput(CP00)` or `dput(head(CP00))`, instead of `head(CP00)`?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to plot 7344 entities into the dendrogram or only several countries?

If several countries: for `dist` function, you have CP00 in a long format (1 value per line per object), however, the `dist` function needs a wide format (1 object per row, multiple properties as columns; see https://www.statology.org/long-vs-wide-data/).

The rectangles can be added simply by the `rect.hclust` function from `stats` package:
https://rdrr.io/r/stats/rect.hclust.html

Comment: There are only 27 countries but with data from feb 2000 to sept 2022. I wanted to display all the 27 countries.